# Starting a second x session crashes a previous one

Tags: xorg, x-server, startx

I am following the guideline in [multiple-desktops-on-one-linux-pc](https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop/multiple-desktops-on-one-linux-pc-now-thats-greedy/) to start another X session.
If I switch to VT-3, I can successfully start a new X session using

```
startx gnome-session -- :1
```

or

```
startx -display :1 -- :1 vt3 &
```

However, when I switch back to my original X session running on VT-7 by pressing 
`Ctrl+Alt+F7`, I find that the X server has crashed and it keeps crashing every time I go back to the second X-server. 
However, if I switch to VT-3 and back to VT-7 without starting a second x session, my original x server does not crash.
And if I switch from my second xserver on tty3 to another tty like tty2 then back to my original x-server on Ctrl-Alt-F7, the xserver does not crash. The crash only happens if I switch from VT-3 to VT-7 after starting a second X session in VT-3.

Looking at `Xorg.0.log` I found these error messages

```
[ 22162.112] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[ 22162.136] (II) event4  - Video Bus: device removed
[ 22162.161] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[ 22162.193] (II) event14 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: device removed
[ 22162.233] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[ 22162.249] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[ 22162.281] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device removed
[ 22162.313] (II) event15 - py-evdev-uinput: device removed
[ 22162.329] (II) event15 - py-evdev-uinput: device removed
[ 22162.361] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 22175.090] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[ 22175.091] (EE) modeset(0): drmSetMaster failed: Invalid argument
[ 22175.091] (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied
[ 22175.091] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 22175.091] (EE) EnterVT failed for screen 0
[ 22175.091] (EE) 
[ 22175.091] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 22175.091] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 22175.091] (EE) 
[ 22175.091] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 22175.134] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I am unsure what the reason for the crash is or how to fix it. Looking up this error message, most people seem to talk about graphic or nvidia drivers, but I did not change the drivers since installing my distro and I don't have an nvidia graphic cards. A similar issue was posted in [question: Switching to a second X session kills the first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463550/switching-to-a-second-x-session-kills-the-first), but I don't think I have the driver problem as `grep "nouveau" /var/log/syslog` returns nothing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you switch to VT-3, **no nothing**, then switch back to VT-7?

Comment: Do you mean if I don't start an x-server? Then nothing happens, my original x-server does not crash (Edited the question to include this info)

Comment: I would edit the question to add that. So others don't get side tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the manual you were following is too old and does not reflect the fact that modern display managers does not have to support multiple sessions started by `startx`. For example this is the case of LightDM.
Supported way how to run a new session with LightDM is in using following command:

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

After this command the previous Xsession on VT-7 is locked and a new Xsession is opened on VT-8 so another user can log in.
Switching between sessions by using `CTRL`-`ALT`-`F7` and `CTRL`-`ALT`-`F8` works as usual (this switching does not lock the previous Xsession).

I posted an answer in the question [Switching to a second X session kills the first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463550/switching-to-a-second-x-session-kills-the-first) you mentioned because this question specifically mentions LightDM.

Another display managers have their own way (GDM probably uses `gdmflexiserver`) so solution for you depends on the display manager you use.

If there is a necessity to run another Xserver (besides the one already running) you could try to follow thorough answer https://askubuntu.com/a/519164/981550 (from question https://askubuntu.com/questions/518454/what-does-startx-command-do) which proposes using `Xnest` (a graphic server-within-a-server).